# Getting the latest browser definitions for MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobile

Could anybody tell me if it's possible to get the latest browser definitions, so I can add them to my App_Browsers folder? I ask this as some mobile phones are not being served the mobile website. When debugging these particular cases, (Browser.IsMobileDevice) is displaying 'false'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to read the Browser's API and its dev documents to get the `Browser.IsMobileDevice` method to be true.

Initially (By Default) every mobile device that has the property of a cellular phone are provided the files that have a **.Mobile.** extension included in their names. So, each time you run the page from a Browser that has No JavaScript, and other essential plugins for the websites. They are thought to be mobile devices. Some of the basics are the headers included in the request too. Server would use the Headers too to get the OS and other properties. You should leave that to Server (I would recommend).

From the MSDN `.isMobileDevice`: [Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

A qoute from the website:

> Gets a value indicating whether the browser is a recognized mobile device.

According to the above qoute, the Server won't get to know that the device is a Mobile Device or not, only that it does, is that it runs a slight test on the Headers and then check whether the device would be a Mobile or not. If it is a mobile device then it returns **true** otherwise it is **false**.

I would advise you to use CSS3 Media Query to change the layout, if the only difference among all the web pages is the styling technique and not the web content and the dynamic data changes in the content.

[CSS3 Media Queries (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)